# Create magnifier for image on user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have a jpg loaded into a image control on a user form. I am trying to create a magnifier for the image so that when the left mouse button is held down it shows a second image control with a blown up image of that section of the jpg. I am getting a compile error "Invalid use of property" on the `newBitmap = tempBitmap` line in the `Private Sub SaveZoomedAreaToFile` with no code or any further explanation.

```
Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 1 Then 
        IsMouseDown = True
        UpdateMagnifiedView X, Y
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If IsMouseDown Then
        UpdateMagnifiedView X, Y
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    If Button = 1 Then 
        IsMouseDown = False
        Image2.Picture = LoadPicture("")
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMagnifiedView(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Dim magnifiedX As Single
    Dim magnifiedY As Single
    
    magnifiedX = X / Image1.Width * Image1.Picture.Width
    magnifiedY = Y / Image1.Height * Image1.Picture.Height
    
    Dim zoomedX As Single
    Dim zoomedY As Single
    
    zoomedX = magnifiedX - (Image2.Width / MagnificationFactor / 2)
    zoomedY = magnifiedY - (Image2.Height / MagnificationFactor / 2)
    
    Image2.Picture = GetZoomedArea(zoomedX, zoomedY, Image2.Width / MagnificationFactor, Image2.Height / MagnificationFactor)

End Sub

Private Function GetZoomedArea(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Width As Single, ByVal Height As Single) As StdPicture

    Dim TempPicturePath As String
    TempPicturePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "TempZoomImage.jpg"
    
    SaveZoomedAreaToFile X, Y, Width, Height, TempPicturePath
    Set GetZoomedArea = LoadPicture(TempPicturePath)

End Function

Private Sub SaveZoomedAreaToFile(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single, ByVal Width As Single, ByVal Height As Single, ByVal FilePath As String)

    Dim tempBitmap As StdPicture
    Set tempBitmap = Image1.Picture

    Dim newBitmap As StdPicture
    Set newBitmap = CreateObject("StdPicture")

    Set newBitmap = tempBitmap

    SavePicture newBitmap, FilePath

End Sub
```

Comment: As bitmaps are objects, you need to use the keyword `Set`: `Set newBitmap = tempBitmap`

Comment: Thank you FunThomas I missed that. With this correction it now runs with no error but it only creates a zoomed image of the very center of the original image. It is not using the x & y corrodents to get the point of the mouse click. As I run through the code it does capture the correct corrodents and calculates the correct position. It is not using them though when rendering the zoomed image.

Comment: I updated the code above with the "Set" added

Comment: I don't see where you do anything with X, Y, Width and Height. `SaveZoomedAreaToFile` will always write the full bitmap. But I have no clue how to rewrite the code - I doubt that it is possible at all with regular VBA functionality.

Comment: I have added the x/y and cropping in another question as it is a new issue. It can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77932550/crop-image-on-user-form