# Use cropped image to create magnifier on user form

Tags: excel, vba

I have userform1 for viewing jpg's from a list of urls. I find the url the user selected  from the list, download the jpg to a temp file and then load it in to a image control on userform1. I am creating a magnifier with the left mouse button and a magnification selector with the right mouse button. When the right mouse button is clicked it brings up userform2 where the user selects the magnification they want and it is stored in a textbox on userform1. The magnification selector works fine. There is a second image control on the userform1 that is only visible when the left mouse button is depressed and is suppose to show the magnified image. To get the magnified image I retrieve the downloaded image from the temp file, cropping it and then resave it as a new temp file. I then load the resaved-cropped image into the second image control. The second image control is then centered on the mouse corrodents and made visible. Everything works except the cropping of the image. I receive a error saying that the cropping contains negative number and can't be performed. I am lost. The only thing I can figure is that during the cropping the image size is decreasing so the cropping is larger than the image. I structured the code so that the cropping is bottom then top and right then left. Even if the image size decreases by doing it in this order it should never be negative.

```
Private Sub UpdateMagnifiedView(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

    Debug.Print "Control Corrodents X=" & X & " Y=" & Y
    Debug.Print ""
    Debug.Print "Image Size W=" & Image1.Picture.Width & " H=" & Image1.Picture.Height
    Debug.Print ""
    
    Dim XCrop As Long
    Dim YCrop As Long
    Dim CLeft As Long
    Dim CTop As Long
    Dim CRight As Long
    Dim CBottom As Long

    XCrop = Image1.Picture.Width / Image1.Width * X
    YCrop = Image1.Picture.Height / Image1.Height * Y
    
    CLeft = XCrop - (XCrop * (TextBox1.Value / 100))
    CRight = XCrop + (XCrop * (TextBox1.Value / 100))
    
    CTop = YCrop - (YCrop * (TextBox1.Value / 100))
    CBottom = YCrop + (YCrop * (TextBox1.Value / 100))
    
    Debug.Print "Pixel Corrodents XCrop=" & XCrop & " YCrop=" & YCrop
    Debug.Print ""
    
    Debug.Print "Crop from Left = " & CLeft
    Debug.Print "Crop from Right = " & CRight
    Debug.Print "Crop from Top = " & CTop
    Debug.Print "Crop from Bottom = " & CBottom
    
    Crop_Image TempFilePath, TempPicturePath, CLeft, CTop, CRight, CBottom
    
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture("")
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(TempPicturePath)
    
End Sub

Sub Crop_Image(StartImage As String, FinishImage As String, CLeft As Long, CTop As Long, CRight As Long, CBottom As Long)

    Dim ImagetoChop As Object
    Dim Chopper As Object
    Dim SaveCropImage As String

    Set ImagetoChop = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    Set Chopper = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    
    ImagetoChop.LoadFile StartImage
    
    Chopper.Filters.Add Chopper.FilterInfos("Crop").FilterID
        
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Bottom") = CBottom
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Right") = CRight
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Left") = CLeft
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Top") = CTop

    Set ImagetoChop = Chopper.Apply(ImagetoChop)

    SaveCropImage = FinishImage

    If Len(Dir(SaveCropImage)) > 0 Then Kill SaveCropImage
    ImagetoChop.SaveFile SaveCropImage

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let me give credit to Daniel Pineault on DevHut. His article "How to Crop an Image Using WIA in VBA" gave me everything I needed to work out this code (https://www.devhut.net/how-to-crop-an-image-using-wia-in-vba/). Here is the completed code for my userform to: Display images in a image control from a URL. Cycle between images with a next and previous buttons, Select a magnification level, Magnify the image based on selection and the x/y coordinates of the mouse click:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" _
    (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal szFileName As String, _
     ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private currentImageIndex As Long
Private imageUrls As Variant

Private IsMouseDown As Boolean
Private TempFilePath As String
Private TempPicturePath As String

Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Check if temporary files exist and delete them
    If Dir(TempFilePath) <> "" Then
        Kill TempFilePath
    End If
    
    If Dir(TempPicturePath) <> "" Then
        Kill TempPicturePath
    End If
    
    Unload Me
    
    Exit Sub ' Exit sub if no errors occur
    
ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle errors here
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume Next ' Resume execution after error
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim Ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws3 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws4 As Worksheet
    Dim Ws5 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim RowJob As Range
    Dim JobUUID As String
    
    ' Set visibility of form elements
    btnNext.Visible = True
    btnPrevious.Visible = True
    lbClose.Visible = False
    
    ' Define temporary file paths
    On Error Resume Next
    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "Temp_image.jpg"
    TempPicturePath = Environ$("temp") & "\" & "TempZoomImage.jpg"
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    
    ' Set references to worksheets
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    Set Ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Attachments")
    Set Ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AllbyStaff")
    Set Ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Santiago")
    Set Ws4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Jim")
    Set Ws5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    
    ' Find row containing CtrName in different sheets
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If Not (Ws2.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing) Then
        Set RowJob = Ws2.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ElseIf Not (Ws3.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing) Then
        Set RowJob = Ws3.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ElseIf Not (Ws4.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing) Then
        Set RowJob = Ws4.Columns("G").Find(CtrName, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    
    ' Get JobUUID from Ws2 based on RowJob
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    JobUUID = Ws2.Cells(RowJob.Row, 4).Value
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling

    ' Find the last row in Ws1
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    lastRow = Ws1.Cells(Ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling

    ' Initialize imageUrls array
    ReDim imageUrls(1 To 1)

    ' Retrieve image URLs for JobUUID
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Ws1.Cells(i, "H").Value = JobUUID Then
            imageUrls(UBound(imageUrls)) = "https://api.servicem8.com/api_1.0/Attachment/" & Ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value & ".file"
            ReDim Preserve imageUrls(1 To UBound(imageUrls) + 1)
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling

    ' Trim the imageUrls array
    If UBound(imageUrls) > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve imageUrls(1 To UBound(imageUrls) - 1)
    End If

    ' Set current image index
    currentImageIndex = 1
    
    ' Set form dimensions and positions of buttons
    With Me
        .Width = Application.Width
        .Height = Application.Height
        .Left = Application.Left
        .Top = Application.Top
    End With
    
    ' Position Next button
    With btnNext
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 50
        .Left = Me.Width - 100
        .Top = (Me.Height / 2) - (.Height / 2)
    End With
    
    ' Position Previous button
    With btnPrevious
        .Width = 50
        .Height = 50
        .Left = 50
        .Top = (Me.Height / 2) - (.Height / 2)
    End With
    
    ' Position Close button
    With btnClose
        .Width = 100
        .Height = 50
        .Left = Me.Width - 150
        .Top = Me.Height - 100
    End With
    
    ' Set value of TextBox1
    TextBox1.Value = Ws5.Cells(2, 1).Value
        
    ' Display current image
    ShowCurrentImage

Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation

End Sub

Private Sub ShowCurrentImage()

    ' Declare variables
    Dim imageUrl As String
    
    ' Check if the currentImageIndex is within the bounds of the imageUrls array
    If UBound(imageUrls) >= currentImageIndex Then
        On Error Resume Next
        ' Attempt to assign the URL from the imageUrls array to the imageUrl variable
        imageUrl = imageUrls(currentImageIndex)
        ' Reset error handling to default
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    
    ' Call subroutine to load image from URL
    LoadImageFromURL imageUrl, TempFilePath
    
    ' Call subroutine to display image on user form
    ShowImageOnUserForm TempFilePath
    
    ' Resize the image control on the user form
    ResizeImageControl

End Sub

Private Sub LoadImageFromURL(ByVal url As String, ByVal TempFilePath As String)

    ' Enable error handling
    On Error Resume Next
    
    ' Download image from URL to temporary file path
    URLDownloadToFile 0, url, TempFilePath, 0, 0
    
    ' Reset error handling to default
    On Error GoTo 0
    
End Sub

Private Sub ShowImageOnUserForm(ByVal TempFilePath As String)

    ' Check if the temporary file path contains a file
    If Len(Dir(TempFilePath)) > 0 Then
        ' Load picture from the temporary file path and display it on the user form
        Me.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(TempFilePath)
    Else
        ' If the file is not found, display an error message
        MsgBox "Error loading image from URL.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeImageControl()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Enable error handling
    
    Dim originalWidth As Single
    Dim originalHeight As Single
    Dim aspectRatio As Single
    
    ' Get the original width and height of the image
    originalWidth = Image1.Picture.Width
    originalHeight = Image1.Picture.Height
    
    ' Calculate the aspect ratio
    aspectRatio = originalWidth / originalHeight
    
    ' Resize the image control based on aspect ratio
    If originalWidth > originalHeight Then
        Image1.Width = Application.UsableWidth * 0.8
        Image1.Height = Image1.Width / aspectRatio
    Else
        Image1.Height = Application.UsableHeight
        Image1.Width = Image1.Height * aspectRatio
    End If

    ' Set the picture size mode to zoom
    Image1.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom

    ' Center the image control vertically and horizontally on the form
    Image1.Top = (Me.Height - Image1.Height) / 2
    Image1.Left = (Me.Width - Image1.Width) / 2

Exit Sub ' Exit the subroutine if no error occurs
ErrorHandler: ' Handle errors
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Private Sub btnNext_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Enable error handling
    
    ' Increment the current image index
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex + 1
    
    ' If it exceeds the upper bound of image URLs, reset it to 1
    If currentImageIndex > UBound(imageUrls) Then
        currentImageIndex = 1
    End If
    
    ' Show the current image
    ShowCurrentImage
    
    ' Refresh the visibility of the image control
    Image1.Visible = False
    Image1.Visible = True

Exit Sub ' Exit the subroutine if no error occurs
ErrorHandler: ' Handle errors
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click()
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler ' Enable error handling
    
    ' Decrement the current image index
    currentImageIndex = currentImageIndex - 1
    
    ' If it becomes less than 1, set it to the upper bound of image URLs
    If currentImageIndex < 1 Then
        currentImageIndex = UBound(imageUrls)
    End If
    
    ' Show the current image
    ShowCurrentImage
    
    ' Refresh the visibility of the image control
    Image1.Visible = False
    Image1.Visible = True

Exit Sub ' Exit the subroutine if no error occurs
ErrorHandler: ' Handle errors
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Button = 1 corresponds to left mouse button
    ' If left mouse button is clicked
    If Button = 1 Then
        ' Set IsMouseDown flag to True to indicate mouse down event
        IsMouseDown = True
        ' Update the magnified view based on the current mouse coordinates
        UpdateMagnifiedView X, Y
        ' Make Image2 visible to display the magnified view
        Image2.Visible = True
    ' Button = 2 corresponds to right mouse button
    ElseIf Button = 2 Then
        ' If right mouse button is clicked, show MagnifierSeL (assuming MagnifierSeL is a user-defined form or object)
        MagnifierSeL.Show
    End If
    
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle any errors that may occur during mouse down event
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub Image1_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Button = 1 corresponds to left mouse button
    ' If left mouse button is released
    If Button = 1 Then
        ' Set IsMouseDown flag to False to indicate mouse up event
        IsMouseDown = False
        ' Clear the picture in Image2 to remove the magnified view
        Image2.Picture = LoadPicture("")
        ' Make Image2 invisible
        Image2.Visible = False
    End If
    
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Handle any errors that may occur during mouse up event
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub

Private Sub UpdateMagnifiedView(ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    Dim XCrop As Long
    Dim YCrop As Long
    Dim CLeft As Long
    Dim CTop As Long
    Dim CRight As Long
    Dim CBottom As Long
    Dim ScaleFactor As Long
    
    ' Determine the scale factor based on TextBox1 value
    Select Case TextBox1.Value
        Case 2
            ScaleFactor = 500
        Case 4
            ScaleFactor = 400
        Case 6
            ScaleFactor = 300
        Case 8
            ScaleFactor = 200
        Case 10
            ScaleFactor = 100
        Case Else
            ' Handle unexpected values in TextBox1
            MsgBox "Invalid value in TextBox1"
            Exit Sub
    End Select
    
    Dim ImagetoChop As Object
    Dim TempFilePath As String ' Assuming TempFilePath is defined elsewhere
    Dim TempPicturePath As String ' Assuming TempPicturePath is defined elsewhere
    
    Set ImagetoChop = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    
    ImagetoChop.LoadFile TempFilePath

    ' Calculate the crop dimensions
    XCrop = (ImagetoChop.Width / Image1.Width) * X
    YCrop = (ImagetoChop.Height / Image1.Height) * Y
    
    CLeft = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, XCrop - ScaleFactor)
    CRight = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, ImagetoChop.Width - XCrop - ScaleFactor)
    CTop = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, YCrop - ScaleFactor)
    CBottom = WorksheetFunction.Max(0, ImagetoChop.Height - YCrop - ScaleFactor)

    ' Position the magnified image
    Image2.Left = Image1.Left + X - (Image1.Width / 3)
    Image2.Top = Image1.Top + Y - (Image1.Height / 3)
    
    ' Crop the image
    Crop_Image TempFilePath, TempPicturePath, CLeft, CTop, CRight, CBottom
    
    ' Load the cropped image into Image2
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture("")
    Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(TempPicturePath)
        
    ' Resize Image2 to maintain aspect ratio
    Image2.Width = 500
    Image2.Height = 500
    
    If Image2.Picture.Width > Image2.Picture.Height Then
        Image2.Width = (Image2.Picture.Width / Image2.Picture.Height) * Image2.Width
    ElseIf Image2.Picture.Height > Image2.Picture.Width Then
        Image2.Height = (Image2.Picture.Height / Image2.Picture.Width) * Image2.Height
    End If
    
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End Sub

Sub Crop_Image(StartImage As String, FinishImage As String, CLeft As Long, CTop As Long, CRight As Long, CBottom As Long)
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    
    ' Declare variables
    Dim ImagetoChop As Object
    Dim Chopper As Object
    Dim SaveCropImage As String
    
    ' Create WIA objects
    Set ImagetoChop = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    Set Chopper = CreateObject("WIA.ImageProcess")
    
    ' Load the image file to crop
    ImagetoChop.LoadFile StartImage
    
    ' Add crop filter to the image process
    Chopper.Filters.Add Chopper.FilterInfos("Crop").FilterID
    
    ' Set the crop properties
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Bottom") = CBottom
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Right") = CRight
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Left") = CLeft
    Chopper.Filters(1).Properties("Top") = CTop
    
    ' Apply the crop to the image
    Set ImagetoChop = Chopper.Apply(ImagetoChop)
    
    ' Specify the filename to save the cropped image
    SaveCropImage = FinishImage
    
    ' Check if the file already exists and delete it
    If Len(Dir(SaveCropImage)) > 0 Then Kill SaveCropImage
    
    ' Save the cropped image
    ImagetoChop.SaveFile SaveCropImage
    
    ' Exit the subroutine
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    ' Display error message
    MsgBox "An error occurred: " & Err.Description
End Sub
```

Hope this helps somebody else, there doesn't seem to be much current information out there for this.